# Pass data in google app engine using POST

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-post, http-get

I'm trying to pass a variable from one page to another using google app engine, I know how to pass it using GET put putting it in the URL.  But I would like to keep the URL clean, and I might need to pass a larger amount of data, so how can pass info using post.

To illustrate, I have a page with a series of links, each goes to /viewTaskGroup.html, and I want to pass the name of the group I want to view based on which link they click (so I can search and get it back and display it), but I'd rather not use GET if possible.

I didn't think any code is required, but if you need any I'm happy to provide any needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links inherently generate `GET` requests. If you want to generate a `POST` request, you'd need to either:

- Use a form with `method="POST"` and submit it, or
- Use AJAX to load the new page.

Comment: K, that's what I was thinking I would need to do but I was kinda hoping for an easier way.  Thanks :)